# Why does the fit and the partial_fit of the sklearn LatentDirichletAllocation return different results ?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

What is strange is that it seems to be exactly the same code for the fit and for the partial_fit.

You can see the code at the following link :

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/c957249/sklearn/decomposition/online_lda.py#L478

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not exactly the same code; `partial_fit` uses `total_samples`:

"
    total_samples : int, optional (default=1e6)
        Total number of documents. Only used in the partial_fit method."

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/c957249/sklearn/decomposition/online_lda.py#L184

(**partial fit**) https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/c957249/sklearn/decomposition/online_lda.py#L472

(**fit**) https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/c957249/sklearn/decomposition/online_lda.py#L510

Just in case it is of your interest: `partial_fit` is a good candidate to be used whenever your dataset is really really big. So, instead of running into possible **memory problems** you perform your fitting in smaller batches, which is called **incremental learning**.

So, in your case you should take into account that `total_samples` default's value is `1000000.0`. Therefore, if you don't change this number and your real number of samples is bigger then you'll get different results from the `fit` method and `fit_partial`. Or maybe it could be the case that you are using mini-batches in the `fit_partial` and not covering all the samples that you provide to the `fit` method. And even if you do this right, you could also get different results, as stated in the documentation:

- "the incremental learner itself may be unable to cope with new/unseen targets classes. In this case you have to pass all the possible classes to the first partial_fit call using the classes= parameter."
- "[...] choosing a proper algorithm is that all of them don’t put the same importance on each example over time [...]"

sklearn documentation: https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/scaling_strategies.html#incremental-learning